# How to correctly call a function of a module in a file that includes mutiple modules in F#

Tags: f#

After reading [F# moudles doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/modules), I am still obfuscated by the use of modules.

`MyTest.fs` file

```fs
module MyTest

module MyModule1 =
    let f =
        // thread sleep
        printfn "hi from module 1"

module MyModule2 =
    let f =
        printfn "hi from module 2"
```

`Program.fs` file

```fs
// entry point
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    MyTest.MyModule2.f
    0
```

I want to only use function named f in MyModule2. When I use `dotnet run` from the project, the output is different from what I thought, which the output I thought may be `hi from module 2`.

```
$ dotnet run
hi from module 1
hi from module 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Those `f` things are not functions, but *values*. They get initialized at program start, and the way they're initialized, as you wrote it, is by calling `printfn` and assuming its return value.

To make them functions, give them parameters:

```
module MyModule1 =
    let f x =
        // thread sleep
        printfn "hi from module 1"

module MyModule2 =
    let f x =
        printfn "hi from module 2"

// entry point
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    MyTest.MyModule2.f 42
    0
```

Since you don't actually do anything with parameters, a better style is to use parameters of type `unit`, which has only one possible value, and that value is denoted `()`:

```
module MyModule1 =
    let f () =
        // thread sleep
        printfn "hi from module 1"

module MyModule2 =
    let f () =
        printfn "hi from module 2"

// entry point
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    MyTest.MyModule2.f ()
    0
```